# Getting infected from gmail login

Tags: gmail

Is there any way at all to get malware or a RAT just from logging in to your gmail account. Not by opening attachments or clicking licks, just from logging in. And I mean real gmail, not a phising attack.

Answer (score 5):

It would be in theory possible that google gets infected and serves malware, although I consider this highly unlikely. More likely is that such an attack is done by malicious browser extensions or attacks through advertisements ([malvertisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertisement)), i.e. things which are outside of the control of google. And of course a man in the middle attacks might be possible too, especially if you have already one of the [known bad certificates](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/11/dell-does-superfish-ships-pcs-with-self-signed-root-certificates/) on the computer or have an [ad injecting software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfish) installed.